# Linking problems with jsoncpp

Tags: c++, json, linker, jsoncpp

I'm trying to use the amalgamated version of jsoncpp in my own project. When using my makefile, it complains that it doesn't find json_tool.h:

```
input/jsoncpp.cpp:193:23: fatal error: json_tool.h: No such file or directory
#include "json_tool.h"
```

In my makefile I have:

```
jsoncpp.o: input/jsoncpp.cpp input/json/json.h
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c input/jsoncpp.cpp $(LIBS)
```

with jsoncpp.cpp and json/json.h the ones created by the amalgamate.py script. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not set up your include path properly

Add the following to your build command:

```
-I input/json/
```

Comment: Good point. (Though it should be `-I input/`.) We should be using `#include "json/json.h"` instead of `#include <json/json.h>`. [Fixed](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/pull/173).

Comment: @cdunn Yeah granted :) I guess it's down to you to provide an authoritative answer now :)

Comment: `s/intented/intended/`